# Note combination doesn't sound right on my digital piano

Tags: sound, digital-piano

So I have a digital piano Thomann DP-26, but I have problems with a piece. The song sounds overhaul good, but the notes I marked sound really off to me. I don't know why, in the midi tutorial and in the original song they sound correct, but on my piano they don't. How do I solve this? I am still a beginner pianist. The song is called *Ad la Lib* and I am playing this cover: 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't hear how *you* play this, of course, but I would take a guess at the problem:

1. you are playing the left hand chords too loud compared with the right hand - possibly because they are slower and "easier to play".
2. The three notes of each A Bb D chord should not all be played at the *same* volume. If the Bb is loudest, the D a bit quieter, and the A quieter still, it will sound "colorful" rather than "dissonant".

Learning to balance the dynamics of each hand separately, and the dynamics of simultaneous notes played by one hand, are the keys to making *anything* sound "musical" rather than "robotic" - but it's not easy!

You can start learning this when you practise your scales and arpeggios. To get started, exaggerate the differences - play a slow scale with the right hand ff and the left hand pp, then the other way round. For the second problem, play a slow scale in octaves with your thumb playing ff and your pinky finger pp, then the other way round. As you get the "feel" of this, increase the speed, and reduce the difference in the dynamic levels.

Eventually, doing this becomes automatic most of the time - but that won't happen overnight!

Answer (score 0):

I can hear the notes just after 50 seconds. They sound fine to me. The chord do have a rather strong dissonance, A-Bb. I'm not sure how I'd analyze it. It may not have a simple Roman numeral analysis. However, the A is continued through three measures so the whole thing sounds fine.